# What would be the better way to write this dart iteration and return a list

Tags: flutter, dart

The purpose is to do some sort of join. Get each user doc from the user document in firestore and attach it to some collection by uid. Then return the collection with the user document full details rather than just the uid.

```
Future<List<ChatRoom>> getChatsrooms(uid) async {
    ChatRoom chatroom = new ChatRoom();
    try {
      List<ChatRoom> chatrooms = new List();
      var snapshots = await _db
          .collection('my-chats-chats')
          .where('users', arrayContains: uid)
          .orderBy('updated_at', descending: true)
          .get();

      for (var room in snapshots.docs) {
        chatroom.chatroomid = room.data()['chatroomid'];
        chatroom.users = room.data()['users'];
      
        // get user profile that isn'nt u.
        List<dynamic> userids = await room.data()['users']
          ..remove(uid);

        var doc = await _db.collection('my-chats-users').doc(userids[0]).get();

        UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(doc.data());

        chatroom.users.add(user);

        // Remove the users string UID from users list
        chatroom.users.remove(user.uid);
        chatroom.users.remove(uid);

        chatrooms.add(chatroom);

      }

      return chatrooms.toList();
 
    } catch (e) {
      print("Couldn't get user\'s chatrooms exception: " + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The above seems to do what I want, except the chatrooms list returned, only contains duplicates of one chat room. So even there are 10 different chat rooms, I am only getting duplicates of one chatroom 10 times.

What I am thinking of is the `chatrooms.add(chatroom);` only adds one item. But the chatrooms list is supposed to be a growable list. So why is it ending up with just one duplicated item?

What would be the better way to write this?

Comment: You have a single `ChatRoom` instance because you created only one. Move `ChatRoom chatroom = new ChatRoom();` to the beginning of the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for seeing that. My bad.